# Merge data.frame rows by consecutive index

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have a `data.frame` of linear intervals, where each interval also has a numeric index:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("id1","id20","id7","id12","id15"),
                 start = c(36, 41, 216, 234, 300),
                 end = c(21, 112, 263, 269, 340),
                 index = c(11, 12, 28, 29, 33))
```

Where `df` is sorted by `index` in ascending order.

I want to merge each set of rows whose indices are consecutive into a single row, such that their `id` is concatenated by a `;`, `start` is the minimum `start` of the set, `end` is the maximum `end` of the set, and `index` is also the maximum `index` of the set.

So for the example above the resulting merged `data.frame` will be:

```
merged.df <- data.frame(id = c("id1;id20","id7;id12","id15"),
                        start = c(36, 216, 300),
                        end = c(112, 269, 340),
                        index = c(12, 29, 33))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) != 1))` to identify where the indices are consecutive.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index) != 1))) %>%
  summarise(id = paste(id, collapse = ";"),
            start = min(start), end = max(end),
            index = last(index)) %>%
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   id       start   end index
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 id1;id20    36   112    12
# 2 id7;id12   216   269    29
# 3 id15       300   340    33
```